# Does installing the DirectX SDK add project templates to Visual Studio?

Tags: directx, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2013 installed on my machine, and I have installed the latest DirectX SDK, but it doesn't seem to have added any DirectX project templates to VS. Should it have? Or do I need to get them separately?

Comment: There is an empty directx project in the sdk which sets you up the device and swapchain, you will just need to start coding. ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about preparing a development environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not supposed to add any templates for you. You have to manual link to wards the include and library folder.

Comment: You may want to check out [Direct3D Win32 Game Visual Studio template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt include it for you, it's your job to point where it is located. Also note if you are using Windows 8 SDK or Windows 8.1 SDK, it includes already DirectX SDK as you can [see here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/07/01/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2013-edition.aspx).